# How to toggle (Expand/Collapse) group data in rdlc

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

In my rdlc report,I want to show my group data just like this example--

[image]

When I click (+) sign group data under the name will expand and  When I click (-) sign group data under the name will collapse.I find resources for SSRS report, but nothing useful for rdlc report in recent times.So I followed in my rdlc according to those SSRC report resources if i can get some result.I followed this two specially--

1. [SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS)](http://ssrs2008.blogspot.in/2010/09/creating-drill-down-report-with-sql.html)
2. [Expand or Collapse All Grouped Items on SSRS Report](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html)

   I took a table.take "GROUP2" as row details.add group parent "GROUP1" for "GROUP2".Like---

[image]

I select group properties for "GROUP2" like--

[image]

then i set visibility hide for "GROUP2" , checked "display can be toggled by this group item" and select "GROUP1" as item.like--

[image]

It gives me report like this--

[image]

there is "GROUP1" item visible, "GROUP2" is hidden but no (+) or (-) sign or button to expand or collapse group data.

**Any one have any idea,What i am missing? or how can i do this in rdlc report like the top example of this question and also i want to set button for "Expand All" and "Collapse All" for this report.**

**EDIT:** I am using asp.net mvc, web api-2 controller.I am tring to get report in pdf format.

Comment: Do the +/- toggles show up if you don't set the group to `Hidden` on report load?

Comment: are you sure, that the name "GROUP1" is the name of textbox?

Comment: yes.it is.I have checked it just now again.

Comment: @MohammadSadiqurRahman, It should works. Did you try recreating the tablix? It is possible you set some unwanted properties while developing further requeriments.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta yes i recreated.no result.I did only thinks that i explained in this question.

Comment: I tried given steps in both SSRS 2008 R2 and VS 2013 in a blank report design, they're working fine as expected (showing expand/collapse sign on parent column). Have you creating/modifying some items which affect expand/collapse functionality inside row group?

Comment: My best guess is something is not named what you think. This is a pretty basic functionality, works in all versions of SSRS.

Comment: is it possible for when i am rendering report in pdf, is there any issue with asp.net/asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to select your column/row group and select group properties.

[image: From your RDLC column right click]

And then select the grouping item from your DataSource

[image: RDLC Group properties/Selecting Group Item from Datasource]

There you go:

Before expanding of group
[image: Before expanding]

After expanding of group
[image: After Expanding]

Comment: Your edit makes sense. PDF doesn't allow you to expand/collapse. It's an excel feature.

Answer (score 0):

First select the table cell showing [GROUP1], and in the Text Box Properties note the Name.  This is not necessarily GROUP1, it could well be Textbox10 etc.

Then in the Text Box Properties for the table cell showing [GROUP2], select that Text Box name below "Display can be toggled by this report item:".

BTW you are likely wasting your time trying to use the expand/collapse functionality in SSRS.  It is generally considered flaky and unreliable, and does not scale.

Answer (score 0):

PDF format does not support toggling.

Ref: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255288.aspx 
(section titled: Toggle items within a report)

"PDF - The report server exports the current show or hide state of the report to PDF. Interactive toggling is not supported"

Answer (score 0):

@MohammadSadiqurRahman Not sure if you got this problem solved but this is something I do that I hope may help you out.

You will need to make sure that your row groupings have been applied correctly. In the example you gave at the top of your post the row group parent would have been set to account type. You would need to make sure this is done for your 'GROUP1'.

Once you have done this set the row visibility for your collapsed row to 'Hide'. Now check the checkbox 'Display can be toggled by this report item' and set the report item to the cell name for the grouped account types.

Personally I attach it to a new label outside of the tablix which will allow for the entire table to expand/collapse with one click. Just depends on how you want it to work.

I hope this helps you out.